# Is this op amp circuit using both negative and positive feedback?

Tags: operational-amplifier

In [this question/answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/276191/resistor-value-in-wheatstone-bridge) theres this op-amp circuit:

[image]

I can't work out whats happening. At a glance the op-amp circuit looks like a cross between a schmitt trigger, differential amplifier and possibly an oscillator! Help!

What is it? What could ut be used for? How does it work? Please assume working knowledge of op-amps but not harder math such as calculus, transfer functions etc

Comment: Start by determining the transfer function for the op amp.

Comment: @Tony Stewart. EE since '75 you need to explain this circuit. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It's a diff amp comparing the fixed value off the offset / null and the value of the sensor. The two 2k resistors look like atlantic attempt at hysteresis but don't seem like very good values.

Answer (score 1):

Without going through the equations it’s hard to tell what’s going on with that circuit and which feedback branch dominates, but the only times I have seen similar things is when people make mistakes.

I once saw an electronics magazine publish a “non-inverting amplifier configuration” for audio applications that just mirrored the resistor location of the inverting one (thus creating a Schmitt trigger).